# Populate JTable using one object per row

Tags: java, swing

I'm sure this is possible but I am having trouble finding the appropriate documentation or a simple example for this situation.

For example's sake, lets say I have an object such as this:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final String address;

    // Constructor, Getters and Setters
}
```

Now I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
myTableModel.addColumn("name");
myTableModel.addColumn("age");
myTableModel.addColumn("address");
myJTable.setModel(myTableModel);
for (Person person : people) {
    myTableModel.addRow(person);
}
```

And then each column would use the row's Person object to "get" its appropriate information to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom TableModel. Here is a sample I wrote some time ago:

https://sourceforge.net/p/puces-samples/code/HEAD/tree/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java

Instead of the NbBundle you can also use a ResourceBundle, if you're not building your application on top of the NetBeans Platform (though I recommend to use a RCP).

Comment: Or are you looking for JavaBeans based solution? I did that once. You can take a look at the following TableModel I wrote, which displays one property per row for a single bean, and combine it with the sample I mentioned before: http://softsmithy.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/softsmithy/lib/main-golden/file/5c4db802573b/lib-core/src/main/java/org/softsmithy/lib/swing/table/PropertyTableModel.java

Comment: Your original answer is what I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: Note: The provided sample is read-only. In case you want to make the model writable/ modifiable: call the according fireXYZ-method of the AbstractTableModel base class after every change. Otherwise the table won't get updated. Just thought this note might save some time. ;-)